# Rerun service every x min with timer not working

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a service that I want to run every X min using (for example) a timer.

This is not working, why? Any better way I can do this? Tried searching and didn't found anything that worked for me...The breakpoint never hits OnStop method...

```
static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine("service has started");
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += scheduleTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    private static void scheduleTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteLine("service is runs again");
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Comment: Start the timer before running the service?

Comment: Not sure, but what about adding in `timer.Enabled = True` after your `timer.Elapsed +=..` statement rather than `timer.Start()` before it?

Comment: Have a read of Thread Timers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a bit same situation earlier. I used the following code, it worked for me.

```
// The main Program that invokes the service   
static class Program
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}


//Now the actual service

public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ///Some stuff

        RunProgram();

        ///////////// Timer initialization
        var scheduleTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        scheduleTimer.Enabled = true;
        scheduleTimer.Interval = 1000;
        scheduleTimer.AutoReset = true;
        scheduleTimer.Start();
        scheduleTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(scheduleTimer_Elapsed);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    void scheduleTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunProgram();
    }

    //This is where your actual code that has to be executed multiple times is placed
    void RunProgram()
    {
     //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: So you dont call Main method? You just call RunProgram again? But don't you need to call Main because there is the Timer set?

Comment: The main method is called anyway when the service is run for the first time. And then all we have to need to re run the RunProgram

Comment: Hmm..With this code my scheduleTimer_Elapsed is never called at all

Comment: And how come when I press "start" in VS it just dies after Main(), shouldn't it be calling RunProgram() every min until I press stop?

Comment: In the above code the timer is set for 1000 milliseconds. Did you try placing a debugger in the RunProgramm. Does the controls gets in there? Can you please post the entire code?

Comment: I have updated now. The breakpoint WriteLine first time (called from main). But never from Elapsedevent

Comment: My bad. I should not have talked about Main method. I am sorry. It is the `protected override void OnStart(string[] args)` method you have to write the first block. Updated the answer

Comment: Is the OnStart called automatically after Main? Note sure how that works. Will try your code

Comment: But my breakpoint never hits OnStart()..? Do I need to call it from Main?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64949/discussion-between-shadow-and-krillezzz).